# woocommerce add a placeholder for each field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the below code and Its getting the placeholder value from the field key which its defined in the first code. How can I add a different placeholder for each value?

```
/* new field under Billing */
// Custom function that handle the Custom field settings
function custom_checkout_fields_settings_vat() {
    $text_domain = 'toBeTranslatd';

    return array(
        'vat' => __('VAT', 'toBeTranslatd'),
        'phone' => __('Phone Number', 'toBeTranslatd'),
    );
}

// Add custom billing fields to Checkout and My account edit addresses
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'custom_billing_fields' );
function custom_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    $settings = custom_checkout_fields_settings_vat(); // Load settings

    // Loop through setting fields
    foreach ( $settings as $field_key => $field_label ) {
        $fields['billing_'.$field_key] = array(
            'type'        => 'text',
            'label'       => $field_label,
            'placeholder' => $field_label,
            'class'       => $field_key === 'vat' ? array('form-field-wide') : array('form-field-wide'),
            'required'    => $field_key === 'vat' ? false : true,
            'clear'       => true,
            'priority'    => $field_key === 'vat' ? 31 : 32,
        );
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

I changed the placeholder to

```
'placeholder' => $field_key === 'vat' ? 15 VAT number : 050011223344,
```

but it broke my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value should be a string

```
'placeholder' => $field_key === 'vat' ? '15 VAT number' : '050011223344',
```